# No module named MySQLdb error even though its installed

Tags: python, ubuntu, path

I keep getting the following error whenI run my python script,I have the "sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb" installed,i have tried to check if its installed by using
"dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql" and check if mysqld is in the PATH,what am I missing here?how to debug this issue?

checking if mysqldb is installed

```
username@machinename:/local/mnt/workspace/cdit$ dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql
akonadi-backend-mysql                           install
libmysqlclient-dev                              install
libmysqlclient18                                install
libmysqlclient18:i386                           install
libqt4-sql-mysql                                install
libqt4-sql-mysql:i386                           install
mysql-client-core-5.5                           install
mysql-common                                    install
mysql-server-core-5.5                           install
python-mysqldb                                  install
```

PATH:-

```
username@machine:/local/mnt/workspace$ echo $PATH
/pkg/wts/qct/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games:/pkg/icetools/bin:/pkg/hwtools/bin:/pkg/netscape/bin:/pkg/gnu/bin:/prj/vlsi/tools/bin:/usr/bin/mysql:/usr/sbin/mysqld
```

ERROR:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 40, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

Comment: what does `which -a python` output?

Comment: **username@machinename:/local/mnt/workspace$ which -a python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/X11/python**

Comment: ok then that is the problem, `apt-get` installs for `usr/bin/python` and you are using  `/usr/local/bin/python` , try  `/usr/bin/python` then import the module

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - how to install it in  `/usr/local/bin/python`

Comment: You should use pip, which python does pip point to? Or do you have pip installed?

Comment: i have pip and  installed using pip

Comment: yes it worked,but looks like what you pointed out is the problem ,its installed in usr/bin/python,how do I get it installed in /usr/local/bin/python

Comment: did installing with pip not work?

Comment: installing with pip did not work,its installed in usr/bin/python

Comment: If you type python what shell starts, usr/bin or /usr/local

Comment: username@machinename:/local/mnt/workspace/$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jan 21 2015, 16:45:36) 
[GCC 4.4.7] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

Comment: I will add the steps as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `/usr/local/bin/python` you can add the path to bashrc:

`export PATH=/usr/local/bin/python:$PATH`

Then `source .bashrc`.

Download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py):

Then run `python get-pip.py`.

Finally run  `sudo pip install your_package`

For system wide changes create a file `/etc/profile.d/whatever.sh` and add the export line to that.